# Using html5 to drag and drop, change from drop(event) to allowDrop(event)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

This is my first post on here, I apologize in advance if the formatting is not correct.

Using html5 to drag and drop I would like to have the ondrop value change from drop(event) to allowDrop(event) after a child has been dropped into the container.

The reason for this is so that once a child object has been dropped into the container, the user would not be allowed to drop an additional child into the same container.

Additionally, I would like the ondrop value to change from allDrop(event) to drop(event) if the child is moved out of the container.

First I have the css and script.

```
<style type="text/css">
div[id^='div']
{float:left; width:100px; height:35px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

Here is a practice html table.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td><div id="div1" ondrop="allowDrop(event)" ondragover="drop(event)"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div6" ondrop="allowDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div7" ondrop="allowDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td><div id="div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">Order 1</div></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">Order 2</div></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div12" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3">Order 3</div></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div13" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4">Order 4</div></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div14" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag5">Order 5</div></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div15" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag6">Order 4</div></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div id="div16" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag7">Order 5</div></div></td></tr>
            </table>            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the ondragover attribute (last line in the code below) worked for me :

```
function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.target.removeAttribute("ondragover");
}
```